# Updating table using JOIN not working correctly

Tags: mysql

I'm doing something like this:

```
UPDATE `widget_list` a
       JOIN `geography` b
       ON b.`zip_code` = a.`zip_code`
SET    b.`msa` = a.`msa`;
```

This executes just fine, but affects no rows. `msa` is set to NULL for all rows as if it wasn't changed at all. `zip_code` and `msa` are the same data types and length and definitely have overlapping `zip_code`. Any idea why this won't update?

EDIT: Update...I tried with a different column name and it ran as well, said that a set of my rows were affected, but none actually changed.

EDIT2: If I do this, then my `msa` column shows NULL for every row. Why wouldn't this value be here for a simple join?

```
  SELECT * FROM `widget_list` a
       JOIN `geography` b
       ON b.`zip_code` = a.`zip_code`
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1264e/1) something else is going on.  Should work.  Need to see sample data in both tables to figure out from here...

Comment: Does `widget_list` have multiple entries with the same zip_code? And it is your intent to change the values in `geography`, correct?

Comment: Yes, the widget_list has multiple with same zip_code. No...I want to change the widget_list. It currently is missing "msa" and I want to join it based on zip code from my geography table which has both zip code and msa.

Comment: If you're wanting to update `widget_list` then your `SET` is backwards...

Comment: @ragerory I've tried it both ways and it hasn't worked. Check out my latest update for some more info.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below should work.

```
UPDATE `widget_list`
SET `msa` = (SELECT `msa` FROM `geography` b
             JOIN `widget_list` a
             ON `a`.`zip_code` = `b`.`zip_code`
             );
```

Comment: Thanks, but getting an error: "You can't specify target table 'widget_list' for update in FROM clause"

Answer (score 0):

Able to reproduce using this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31fc0/1/0)

However by changing the order on the set function it works... as in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9db0aa/1/0)

```
 UPDATE `widget_list` a
       JOIN `geography` b
       ON b.`zip_code` = a.`zip_code`
SET    a.`msa`=b.`msa` ;
```

and again that it should work.. implying it's a setup issue in your enviroment, or we're missing something (trigger perhaps?)

[Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5033c/1/0)  Note however when mopre than one msa exists per zipcode A, X in my example for zip 123... the system simply picks one and uses it to update.  X is lost in my example... are you sure that's not what's happening to you? (it's why I want to see sample data to see if it's a data issue vs syntax vs logic)

updated:

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6929b/1/0) So if your source table has null values in the zipcodes you'll get null values in the destination table...

so what happens if we add....

```
 UPDATE `widget_list` a
       JOIN `geography` b
       ON b.`zip_code` = a.`zip_code`
      and b.msa is not null
SET    a.`msa`=b.`msa` ;
```

and [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe6de/1/0) showing excluded nulls

Comment: This doesn't work, but I know it should. What's strange is that if I do a straight JOIN (no update), I end up with NULL in the MSA column as well. I can update all the columns that appear correctly when I do the straight JOIN(no update)

Comment: mysql combines columns when named the same.  Ensure to alias them both in your select statement, you'll see  geography isn't null then.  at this point I agree it should work.  So without data which may be causing the problem, I'm not sure how to help.  I guess my point is we've proven it works normally.  So something about your setup is preventing it from working.  Any triggers on the table which are changing or preventing data updates on you?

Answer (score -1):

Use from to do **join**.

```
UPDATE widget_list
SET b.msa = a.msa
FROM widget_list a JOIN geography b ON b.zip_code = a.zip_code
```

Comment: I've never had a need for that syntax, a simple join like in the question should be work fine.